# Why group signature based CL signature is in "sign-encrypt-prove" paradigm

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, anonymity

In [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3196507), it referred that there are two paradigms used in constructing group signatures: the *"sign-encrypt-prove"(SEP)* paradigm and *"sign-randomize-proof"(SRP)* paradigm.

As said in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3196507), SEP paradigm is

> Here, a signature is an encrypted membership certificate together with a signature of knowledge, where the signer demonstrates knowledge of some signed value in the ciphertext

SRP paradigm is

> Essentially,they use a signature scheme which supports (1) randomization ofsignatures so that multiple randomized versions of the same sig-nature are unlinkable, and (2) efficiently proving knowledge of asigned value. In their construction, on joining the group, the issuer uses such a signature scheme to sign a commitment to the user’ssecret key. The user can then produce a group signature for a mes-sage by randomizing the signature and computing a signature ofknowledge on the message, which demonstrates knowledge of thesigned secret key.

In my understanding, if using the non-randomized signature scheme to construct group signature scheme, maybe I should follow "SEP", otherwise(using the randomized signature scheme), I should follow "SRP", because in this way I just need to prove the knowledge of signed secret key in the signature, which is easier to prove than that in "SEP".

However, when I read the group signature proposed by [Camenisch, J., and Lysyanskaya](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-28628-8_4), it said that it followed "sign-encrypt-prove" paradigm. The CL signature has re-randomize property, why it doesn't seem to follow the "sign-randomize-proof" paradigm ? In other paper proposed by [David Pointcheval and Olivier Sanders](http://chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/525.pdf), it first proposed the similar randomized signature like CL and followed "SRG" paradigm to construct group signature(concrete construction in Appendix A).

And if CL-group signature indeed follows the SEP, why does it only encrypt the group member public key but not the certificate? That seems to contradict with the SEP as well.

Comment: The CL scheme is simply a SEP scheme. Its exactly like BBS04, but using a different signature scheme. Also SEP is just a rough template and it might not perfectly describe every scheme.